# Sql Server Agrupar y contar

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola lo que necesito hacer es agrupar y contar por 2 campos pero no logro hacerlo. lo que necesito es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo maximo que logro es esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es el query que uso

```
SELECT 
     CASE 
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CVE_DOC order by CVE_DOC) = 1 
         THEN 
             RIGHT(Space(20) + CVE_DOC, 20)
         ELSE 
             RIGHT(Space(20) + CONCAT(CVE_DOC, '-', (ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY CVE_DOC order by cve_doc)-1)), 20)
     END,
     Registros.*
FROM Registros
```

Datos

```
CREATE TABLE Registros(
    CVE_DOC VARCHAR(10),
    CVE_CLPV VARCHAR(10),
    STATUS CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'O',
    DAT_MOSTR BIT DEFAULT 0,
    CVE_PEDI VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('101', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-555')
INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('101', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-555')
INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('101', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-561')
INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('101', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-561')
INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('101', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-578')
INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('101', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-578')
INSERT INTO Registros VALUES('102', '32', 'O', 0, '4126097458-578')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A priori del origen de datos, parece que lo que quieres, se puede solucionar utilizando la función [dense_rank](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/12/dense-rank/). Igual que row_number, pero si dos elementos de la partición se repiten, repite valor.

```
;with c as (
    select *, 
    dense_rank() over(partition by cve_doc order by cve_pedi) as row
from dbo.Registros
)
select case when c.row = 1 then cve_doc 
        else Concat(cve_doc,'-',row) end
    , c.Cve_DOC
    , c.Cve_CLPV
    , c.Status
    , c.Dat_Mostr
    , c.Cve_Pedi
 from c;
```

[image: Resultado]